# C++ Win32 programing. How can I send an array elemens to a listbox?

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

If I have string(data in this case) I am using sendmessage like this:

```
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,IDC_LISTBOX),LB_ADDSTRING,0,(LPARAM)data);
```

But how to do it with array of strings or integers?

Comment: templates ? provide at least the functions' definitions; but the functions' bodies are also of interest

Comment: Read about loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through the array, sending each string individually.  And you have to convert integers to strings before you can send them.